# discord.net Bot does not reset variables after being told to

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

first off, I know, that my question is very bad formulated. I am sorry for that.

I am trying to get my bot to search the status of every user in a guild and if the users status contains a certain string, the user gets a role. Everything works, as it should, aside from one thing. I want to run the command once and the other command will run every x seconds, so the users get updated all the time.

Now, if I add the string to my status and run the bot, it gives me the role every run. when I remove it, while the bot is running, the bot somehow still keeps giving me the role (it is supposed to remove the role and shut up until I add the string again). So it is somehow not updating and thinks, I stil have the role.

I am open for suggestions.

heres the responisble code:

```
        [Command("statuson")]
        [Alias("x")]
        public async Task StatusOn()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("req refresh");
                await JaLOL();
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
```

```
        public int count = 0;
        public async Task JaLOL()
        {
            IReadOnlyCollection<SocketGuildUser> users = null;
            IReadOnlyCollection<IActivity> userActivities = null;
            IReadOnlyCollection<ulong> roles = null;

            Console.WriteLine("refresh");
            users = Context.Guild.Users;
            foreach (IGuildUser user in users)
            {
                userActivities = user.Activities;
                roles = user.RoleIds;
                foreach (ulong role in roles)
                {
                    if (role == 1020762686323167303)
                    {
                        foreach (var activity in userActivities)
                        {
                            if (activity.Type == ActivityType.CustomStatus)
                            {
                                if (!activity.ToString().Contains(".gg/anime-club"))
                                {
                                    await user.RemoveRoleAsync(1020762686323167303);
                                    Console.WriteLine("remove " + user.DisplayName);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                foreach (var activity in userActivities)
                {
                    if (activity.Type == ActivityType.CustomStatus)
                    {
                        if (activity.ToString().Contains(".gg/anime-club"))
                        {
                            await user.AddRoleAsync(1020762686323167303);
                            Console.WriteLine("add " + user.DisplayName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine("end   " + count);
        }
```

Comment: Debug your code, step through the logic line by line and see what's not doing what you think it should be doing.

Comment: I feel like at a minimum you can refactor this to be just one outer foreach loop and condense some of your conditional logic.  Your first foreach loop iterates over the roles, does an if statement, and then does another foreach that iterates over an activity type.  Once all of that is done looping, the second outer foreach loop executes over the activity types again.